# Two fields related in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I need to update my table every time a new value of "sku" is entered (not to create a new entry), but it does have to happen only if the "client" selected is the same. If the "client" is different, then the model should add a new object with the same "sku", but with different "clients".

I have tried to do the following in my models.py:

```
class ProductList(models.Model):
    id_new = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sku = models.CharField(primary_key=False, max_length=200)
    client = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    storage = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    cost_price = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    sell_price = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ncm = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('sku', 'client'),)
```

But it is not working. How can I make that work?

Comment: I don't think it should be done in models. rather it should done in views/forms

Comment: But how could I do that?

Comment: I think issue is different your logic should work of unique together. Issue must at here `get_user_model()` you have mention model name like `ClientMaster` something. Check twice, also make sure you have fired migrate command.

Comment: Can't you do the checking when saving the model by overriding the save() method?

Comment: I guess that could be one solution, but I cannot visualize how to implement that. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
# form

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductList

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs:
        client = self.cleaned_data.get('client')  # get client from form cleaned_data
        if hasattr(self.instance, 'pk') and self.instance.client != client:  # check if client match's already existing instance's client
            self.instance.pk = None  # make a duplicate instance
            self.instance.client = client  # change the client

        return super(MyForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

# views.py
# ...    
def my_view(request, id): 
    instance = get_object_or_404(ProductList, id=id)
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('next_view')
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'form': form})
```

#### Update

Um you can override the model as well. you can try like this:

```
  # Untested Code but should work
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if self.pk:
        current_instance = self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        if current_instance.client != self.client:
           self.pk = None
     return super(ProductList, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I guess that it should work, but another problem that I have is that I am using a django package called django-import-export to do the importation of a .csv file. The procedure to overwrite that could be quite hard to do.

Comment: @MatheusSant'ana I have added a model override as well, which can be used for your django-import-export. But you can use either of the solutions, not both together

Comment: Dude, I am getting an error when I try to update a new model now.

Clientes.models.ProductList.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one ProductList -- it returned 2!

I think that is because I have two models now with the same sku and the package tries to update both. Do you know what can I do to solve that?

Comment: `then the model should add a new object with the same "sku", but with different "clients"` I have answered based on this line of your question :) . But don't worry. If you want to get the latest object, then try `ProductList.objects.filter(sku=sku).last()`; if you want the first, then use `filter(sku=sku).first()`

Comment: I did not understand that. I mean, the "sku" is repeated and when the django-import-export tries to update the value it crashes because there are two fields to update, he does not choose a particular "client" to do that.

Comment: Ah, well, can you please ask another question with how you are using Django Import Export? I can't suggest you anything unless I see any relevant code. Thanks.

Comment: Great, you can see my new question through this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560023/django-import-export-customization-with-related-fields