# Django-import-export customization with related fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-import-export

I need to update my table every time a new value of "sku" is entered (not to create a new entry), but it does have to happen only if the "client" selected is the same. If the "client" is different, then the model should add a new object with the same "sku", but with different "clients".

One StackOverflow user gave me the solution:

```
class ProductList(models.Model):
    id_new = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sku = models.CharField(primary_key=False, max_length=200)
    client = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    storage = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    cost_price = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    sell_price = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ncm = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('sku', 'client'),)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            current_instance = self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if current_instance.client != self.client:
                self.pk = None
        return super(ProductList, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

After I added the save function the problem got solved. However, if I try to update an existing table I get the following problem for each field in my file:

```
Line number: 1 - get() returned more than one ProductList -- it returned 2!
345, Teste 1, Descrição 1, 87654, 59,99, 180, 65, 884, 25

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/checkstore/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 453, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/home/checkstore/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 267, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/home/checkstore/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 261, in get_instance
return instance_loader.get_instance(row)
File "/home/checkstore/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/instance_loaders.py", line 33, in get_instance
return self.get_queryset().get(**params)
File "/home/checkstore/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 403, in get
(self.model._meta.object_name, num)
Clientes.models.ProductList.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one ProductList -- it returned 2!
```

My admin.py file is presented below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import FaturaForm, ConfirmImportForm
from .models import (Token,
                     Sell,
                     LogisticCost,
                     IncomeCost,
                     FinalPayment,
                     CustomerServiceCost,
                     Fatura,
                     ProductList)
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin, ImportMixin
from .resources import ProductListResource
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


try:
    from django.utils.encoding import force_text
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode as force_text
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class ProductAdminImport(ImportExportModelAdmin, ImportMixin):
    resource_class = ProductListResource
    list_display = ('sku', 'client', 'name', 'description', 'storage', 'cost_price', 'sell_price', 'ncm', 'inventory')
    list_filter = ['client']

    def process_import(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Perform the actual import action (after the user has confirmed the import)
        """
        if not self.has_import_permission(request):
            raise PermissionDenied

        confirm_form = ConfirmImportForm(request.POST)
        if confirm_form.is_valid():
            import_formats = self.get_import_formats()
            input_format = import_formats[
                int(confirm_form.cleaned_data['input_format'])
            ]()
            tmp_storage = self.get_tmp_storage_class()(name=confirm_form.cleaned_data['import_file_name'])
            data = tmp_storage.read(input_format.get_read_mode())
            if not input_format.is_binary() and self.from_encoding:
                data = force_text(data, self.from_encoding)
            dataset = input_format.create_dataset(data)
            for i in User.objects.all():
                if i.username == str(request.POST['original_file_name'].split('.')[0]):
                    dataset.append_col([i.id] * dataset.height, header='client')

            result = self.process_dataset(dataset, confirm_form, request, *args, **kwargs)

            tmp_storage.remove()

            return self.process_result(result, request)


    def import_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        Perform a dry_run of the import to make sure the import will not
        result in errors.  If there where no error, save the user
        uploaded file to a local temp file that will be used by
        'process_import' for the actual import.
        '''
        if not self.has_import_permission(request):
            raise PermissionDenied

        resource = self.get_import_resource_class()(**self.get_import_resource_kwargs(request, *args, **kwargs))

        context = self.get_import_context_data()

        import_formats = self.get_import_formats()
        form_type = self.get_import_form()
        form = form_type(import_formats,
                         request.POST or None,
                         request.FILES or None)

        if request.POST and form.is_valid():
            input_format = import_formats[
                int(form.cleaned_data['input_format'])
            ]()
            import_file = form.cleaned_data['import_file']
            # first always write the uploaded file to disk as it may be a
            # memory file or else based on settings upload handlers
            tmp_storage = self.write_to_tmp_storage(import_file, input_format)

            # then read the file, using the proper format-specific mode
            # warning, big files may exceed memory
            try:
                data = tmp_storage.read(input_format.get_read_mode())
                if not input_format.is_binary() and self.from_encoding:
                    data = force_text(data, self.from_encoding)
                dataset = input_format.create_dataset(data)
            except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                return HttpResponse(_(u"<h1>Imported file has a wrong encoding: %s</h1>" % e))
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(
                    _(u"<h1>%s encountered while trying to read file: %s</h1>" % (type(e).__name__, import_file.name)))
            # if str(request.user.username) == str(import_file.name.split('.')[0]):
            for i in User.objects.all():
                csv_client_name = str(import_file.name.split('.')[0])
                if i.username == csv_client_name:
                    dataset.append_col([i.id] * dataset.height, header='client')
            result = resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True,
                                          raise_errors=False,
                                          file_name=import_file.name,
                                          user=request.user)

            context['result'] = result

            if not result.has_errors():
                context['confirm_form'] = ConfirmImportForm(initial={
                    'import_file_name': tmp_storage.name,
                    'original_file_name': import_file.name,
                    'input_format': form.cleaned_data['input_format'],
                })

        context.update(self.admin_site.each_context(request))

        context['title'] = _("Import")
        context['form'] = form
        context['opts'] = self.model._meta
        context['fields'] = [f.column_name for f in resource.get_user_visible_fields()]

        request.current_app = self.admin_site.name
        return TemplateResponse(request, [self.import_template_name],
                                context)


class FaturaModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FaturaForm
    list_filter = ['cliente', 'pago']
    list_display = ('cliente',
                    'id',
                    'dia',
                    'numero_da_fatura',
                    'mes',
                    'ano',
                    'valor',
                    'pago')


class SellsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['client']
    list_display = ['client', 'date']


admin.site.register(Token)
admin.site.register(Sell, SellsAdmin)
admin.site.register(LogisticCost)
admin.site.register(IncomeCost)
admin.site.register(FinalPayment)
admin.site.register(CustomerServiceCost)
admin.site.register(Fatura, FaturaModel)
admin.site.register(ProductList, ProductAdminImport)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you need to update your `ProductListResource`. You can try like this:

```
class ProductListResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductList
        import_id_fields = ('sku','client',)  # <-- Add multiple id fields
        fields = (sku', 'client', 'name', 'description', 'storage',...) # other fields
```

---

**BTW** I don't think you need to override the `save` method for generating duplicate items. If `sku` and `client` are used as multiple identification, **django-import-export** will always create new instances when it sees different `client` for one `sku`.

Comment: Great, it worked like a charm! Sorry to not answer this solution. Thank you so much for taking the time to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

in `save()` function.

```
if current_instance.client != self.client:
    self.pk = None
```

Change to

```
if current_instance.client != self.client:
    self.id_new = None
```

If `self.pk` gives you a value of `self.id_new`, the value assigned to `self.pk` does not apply to `self.id_new`. Exactly, the value of the instance changes immediately, but when you call the `save()` function, the value does not apply to the database.

So I think it causes unexpected duplicated values.

Comment: I have tried that, but the problem unfortunately remains.

Comment: Oh, then, run your code on debug mode, and chase your code. Have to know what makes duplicated data. and check `get` method.

Comment: Yeah, I found the solution this way. I will post it here on monday!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is the following:

In the package file `instance_loaders.py` I modified the function:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return return self.resource._meta.model.objects.all()
```

To:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.resource._meta.model.objects.filter(client=self.dataset._data[0]._row[-1]).all()
```

And that solved all my problems.

Comment: Thats not a good solution. Lets say you have upgraded the version or someone updated it in production, the application will crash. Its better if you write some kind of override in your code, not inside packages

Comment: Yeah, I thought that. Do you know how can I override that? What I did to not crash it if it is updated is to upload a new package with my modifications to pypi, so I can use that instead of the original package.

Comment: I am not sure how you can do that. I will try to dig into that if I can manage spare time(can't guarantee though, so don't rely on that). in the mean time can you try my solution plz?

Comment: Thank you, man! I have just tried your solution and that worked perfectly.

Comment: For future reference: you can subclass `ForeignKeyWidget` and provide your own `get_queryset` method for it. So, in your case, you can create a subclass called `ClientWidget`, then in the `ProductListResource`, add a line:
`client = fields.Field(attribute='client', column_name='client', widget=ClientWidget()` 
Note that I haven't tested this, and you should refer to the source for `ForeignKeyWidget`.

Comment: Great to see another solution for this! Thank you.